# How to get Total count of a person column in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a list named "PendingApproval" in SharePoint 2016 on-premises. When the user login in to the system then in the home page I have to show total Pending Approval request for this loggedin user. I have to filter this by RequestedBy column which is Person type column. In SharePoint Designer I can filter the data by "RequestedBy" column but I am unable to get Total Number of request/count. How can I do this with SharePoint Designer 2013.

I have tried with Data View & Display Item form. I have used `<xsl:value-of select="count(@RequestedBy)" />` but nothing is coming.

Let's say there are 3 request for user SP1 in PendingApproval list, so the output will the 3

My Code:

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True" AsyncRefresh="True" FrameType="None" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="8" Title="PendingApproval" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" ListName="{958ED955-7861-4A22-A727-4EC48F4BBC56}" Default="FALSE" DisplayName="PendingApproval" __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{534BCC5E-21EF-46D2-B4A8-29803F4A8224}" id="g_534bcc5e_21ef_46d2_b4a8_29803f4a8224" pagesize="1" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
    <DataSources>
        <SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" UseServerDataFormat="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;RequestedBy&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Integer&quot;&gt;&lt;UserID/&gt;&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" id="PendingApproval1"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{958ED955-7861-4A22-A727-4EC48F4BBC56}"/><asp:Parameter Name="StartRowIndex" DefaultValue="0"/><asp:Parameter Name="nextpagedata" DefaultValue="0"/><asp:Parameter Name="MaximumRows" DefaultValue="1"/></SelectParameters><DeleteParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{958ED955-7861-4A22-A727-4EC48F4BBC56}"/></DeleteParameters><UpdateParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{958ED955-7861-4A22-A727-4EC48F4BBC56}"/></UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{958ED955-7861-4A22-A727-4EC48F4BBC56}"/></InsertParameters></SharePoint:SPDataSource>
    </DataSources>
    <ParameterBindings>
                                <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{958ED955-7861-4A22-A727-4EC48F4BBC56}"/>
                                <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                                <ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
                                <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
                                <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
                                <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
                                <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                                <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_nextpagedata" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                            </ParameterBindings>
    <datafields>@Title,Title;@ProcessName,ProcessName;@RequestedBy,RequestedBy;@RequestedByName,RequestedByName;@RequestDate,RequestDate;@StatusAtMyTask,StatusAtMyTask;@RequestID,RequestID;@EmployeeID,EmployeeID;@RequestedByEmail,RequestedByEmail;@RequestLink,RequestLink;@IsOverdue,IsOverdue;@ID,ID;@ContentType,Content Type;@Modified,Modified;@Created,Created;@Author,Created By;@Editor,Modified By;@_UIVersionString,Version;@Attachments,Attachments;@File_x0020_Type,File Type;@FileLeafRef,Name (for use in forms);@FileDirRef,Path;@FSObjType,Item Type;@_HasCopyDestinations,Has Copy Destinations;@_CopySource,Copy Source;@ContentTypeId,Content Type ID;@_ModerationStatus,Approval Status;@_UIVersion,UI Version;@Created_x0020_Date,Created;@FileRef,URL Path;@ItemChildCount,Item Child Count;@FolderChildCount,Folder Child Count;@AppAuthor,App Created By;@AppEditor,App Modified By;</datafields>
    <XSL>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
    <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="ManualRefresh"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="dvt_firstrow">1</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="dvt_nextpagedata" />
    <xsl:param name="UserID">CurrentUserName</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>



    <xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($ManualRefresh = 'True')">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="1%" class="ms-vb" valign="top">
                            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/staticrefresh.gif" id="ManualRefresh" border="0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__cancel')}" alt="Click here to refresh the dataview."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvt_1">
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">RepForm3</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RowLimit" select="1" />
        <xsl:variable name="FirstRow" select="$dvt_firstrow" />
        <xsl:variable name="LastRow" select="$FirstRow + $dvt_RowCount - 1" />
        <xsl:variable name="IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0" />
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$dvt_IsEmpty">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.empty"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="1" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$dvt_RowCount" />

                    </xsl:call-template>
                </table>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.commandfooter">
            <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="$FirstRow" />
            <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$LastRow" />
            <xsl:with-param name="RowLimit" select="$RowLimit" />
            <xsl:with-param name="dvt_RowCount" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
            <xsl:with-param name="RealLastRow" select="number(ddwrt:NameChanged('',-100))" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
        <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:variable name="dvt_KeepItemsTogether" select="false()" />
            <xsl:variable name="dvt_HideGroupDetail" select="false()" />
            <xsl:if test="(position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow) or $dvt_KeepItemsTogether">
                <xsl:if test="not($dvt_HideGroupDetail)" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%" class="ms-vb">
                            <b>RequestedBy:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td width="75%" class="ms-vb">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@RequestedBy" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                        </td></tr><tr>
                        <td width="25%" class="ms-vb">
                            <b>count(@RequestedBy):</b>
                        </td>
                        <td width="75%" class="ms-vb">

                            <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(@RequestedBy)" />

                        </td></tr>
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="99" class="ms-vb">
                                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="ID" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID))" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.empty">
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_ViewEmptyText">There are no items to show in this view.</xsl:variable>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="ms-vb">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dvt_ViewEmptyText"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.commandfooter">
        <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
        <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
        <xsl:param name="RowLimit" />
        <xsl:param name="dvt_RowCount" />
        <xsl:param name="RealLastRow" />
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <xsl:if test="$FirstRow &gt; 1 or $dvt_nextpagedata">
                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.navigation">
                        <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="$FirstRow" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$LastRow" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="RowLimit" select="$RowLimit" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="dvt_RowCount" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="RealLastRow" select="$RealLastRow" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.navigation">
        <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
        <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
        <xsl:param name="RowLimit" />
        <xsl:param name="dvt_RowCount" />
        <xsl:param name="RealLastRow" />
        <xsl:variable name="PrevRow">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$FirstRow - $RowLimit &lt; 1">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$FirstRow - $RowLimit" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="LastRowValue">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$LastRow &gt; $RealLastRow">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$LastRow"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$RealLastRow"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="NextRow">
            <xsl:value-of select="$LastRowValue + 1"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:variable>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-paging" align="right">
            <xsl:if test="$dvt_firstrow &gt; 1" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('dvt_firstrow={1};dvt_startposition={}')" />;</xsl:attribute>
                Start</a>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: history.back();</xsl:attribute>
                <img src="/_layouts/15/images/prev.gif" border="0" alt="Previous" />
                </a>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$FirstRow" />
             - <xsl:value-of select="$LastRowValue" />
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>

            <xsl:if test="$LastRowValue &lt; $dvt_RowCount or string-length($dvt_nextpagedata)!=0" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('dvt_firstrow={',$NextRow,'};dvt_startposition={',$dvt_nextpagedata,'}'))" />;</xsl:attribute>
                <img src="/_layouts/15/images/next.gif" border="0" alt="Next" />
                </a>
            </xsl:if>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   </XSL>
</WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since I've used XSLT in web parts. It was "easy" in SharePoint Designer 2010 to build and customize these web parts. If you still have access to a SP2010 server, you could use SPD2010 to create the XSLT using "point and click" and then copy the result. Today I'd search for "SharePoint Designer 2010 XSLT count" to find examples.

The pattern is something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count($Rows[@Age])" />
```

**Why not just use a view with RequestedBy filtered by "[Me]"?** Views can filter and count.

The list:

[image]

The view of the list:

[image]

View setup:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear Mike, thanks for your help but I have to do this with SharePoint designer.

Comment: Mike, In the SharePoint Designer I have used below pattern in Display Item form but still the result is 1, it should be 3
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count($Rows[@Age])" />

Comment: Dear Mike, the pattern helps me a lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To get the count I did below steps

1. From Designer 2013 I have inserted "Display Item Form" for my list, then I filter with "Current User".To get count I have used below pattern(any one)

```
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($Rows[@RequestedBy])"/>
                       or
    <xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@RequestedBy])"/>
```

2. In SharePoint Designer's Paging option I just enable "Display All Items" then total count is coming, after that I changed it to '0' items and the result is same.
3. Finally to show only count I just add some CSS.